# R stops reading a table when coming across "#"

Tags: r, read.table

I'm new to R and I'm trying to read a tsv file where sometimes there is a "#" in the table. R just stopped reading when coming across the "#" and gave me the error:

```
    Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
    line 6227 did not have 6 elements
```

I looked at that line in the file and I found the "#". The data looks like this:

```
    CM School Supply #1    Upland     CA    3   8    Shopping
```

When I delete it R can continue reading the table,but I have more "#"s in the file...

How to set the variables in the read.table()? I tried to search for a solution everywhere but failed... Hope someone here can help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can completely turn off `read.table()`'s interpretation of comment characters (by default set to `"#"`) by setting `comment.char=""` in your call to [`read.table()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html).

Comment: Click through to the help page linked in my answer, or type `?read.table` and read about the function's `comment.char` argument to learn why it works. (And then, to indicate that your question has been answered, you can "accept" my answer by clicking the check-mark just to its left.)